# Vim: Copy/Yank multiple lines which are seperated by some text in just one vim command

Tags: vim

Now for example, I have some text like (all on separate lines):

*

```
1st Line)Who are you?
2nd Line)How are you?
3rd Line)Where are you?
4th Line)Whom are you with?
5th Line)Why are you here?
```

*

What I want do is copy/yank line 1,3,5 in just one vim command and then paste it with the usual paste(p) command using vim.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one slightly manual way to do it, but one of the more slicker manual ways, I think. It can probably be automated with a recording or a function.

```
Position cursor on first line
"ayy
Position cursor on third line
"Ayy  (note the capital A)
Position cursor on fifth line
"Ayy  (again, capital).

Position cursor on place where you want to paste
p
```

The symbol " followed by a letter, before a command like yank, means to yank it into a "named buffer" (there are 26 named buffers I believe, one for each letter), and if you capitalize the letter then it's append, rather than overwrite, to that buffer.

Comment: Hi Starman that's definitely slick! Thanks for the reply and the explanation....but I was wandering if this would be possible without going to any particular line that I want to yank at all. Just doing yanking with my cursor static and knowing the line numbers that I want to yank...

Answer (score 0):

Following would yank the uneven lines into register A.

```
let @a=''|g/^/if (line('.')%2)|y A
```

**Breakdown**

- `let @a=''`         Clear the "a" register
- `g/^/`              for each line
- `if (line('.')%2)`  if the linenumber is uneven
- `y A`               append it to register A

To copy immediately to the end of your file, you can use

```
g/^/if (line('.')%2)|co $
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two command.

**Option 1:**

Search and highlight keywords in each line 
using your example.

```
/\v1|3|5
```

Then use the command

```
:CopyLine
```

which can be found in the [copymatches plugin](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_search_matches)

Then paste with the p command.

i mead a small  [video demo](https://asciinema.org/a/19632)  you can check it out.

**Option 2:**

You can also do it using the Global Command

Fist Empty register A

```
:let @a=''
```

Then use the global command

```
:g/\%1l\|\%3l\|\%5l/y A
```

Then paste with the "ap command.

Comment: Thanks for the response, byaruhaf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to select the lines you are interested in using their line numbers.

In your example, to yank lines 1,3,5 into register `a` the command is:

```
:let @a=''|for c in [1,3,5]|execute c . ',' . c . 'y A'|endfor
```

Then `"a p` will paste these 3 lines at the cursor position.

UPDATE: To include the paste operation in the command as well:

```
:let @a=''|for c in [1,3,5]|execute c . ',' . c . 'y A'|endfor|execute "normal! \"ap\<CR>"
```